# How to check reindex triggers from Magento 2.4 database?

Tags: magento2, database, magento2.4, reindex

I would like to check my database triggers related to stock updates in my Magento 2.4.

I need to know what are the triggers to stock updates specifically.

How could I check it?

Answer (score 0):

It's a native MySQL feature that Magento uses to detect and invalidate the data, so you might be able to check the stock-related ones via this DB query below.

```
select trigger_name from information_schema.triggers where trigger_name like "%stock%";
+----------------------------------------------+
| trigger_name                                 |
+----------------------------------------------+
| trg_cataloginventory_stock_item_after_insert |
| trg_cataloginventory_stock_item_after_update |
| trg_cataloginventory_stock_item_after_delete |
+----------------------------------------------+
```